# Let a, b ∈ Z, where Z is the set of integers. Define a relation S on Z as aSb is even for some number n. Prove that S is an equivalence relation.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

So, I am new to this relations. I have tried to attempt this question by supposing for values but that would not get me anywhere in a formal proof. The question is as follows:

Q. Let a, b ∈ Z, where Z is the set of integers. Define a relation S on Z as aSb

a) iff an + bn is even for some number n

b) iff a^n + b^n is even for some number n

Prove that S is an equivalence relation.

So, I need to prove both of these statements and I am not sure how can I check the properties with it?

To prove a relation we need to check the properties of reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. How can we prove the properties of variables?

NOTE: a and b are 2 different parts. The question is the same though.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Start from the definition of an equivalence relation and work from there: can you prove that $S$ is symmetric? Reflexive? Transitive? (transitivity may be slightly harder but I see a fun trick which makes it pretty simple)

Comment: For a: note the general shape of even numbers: every even number $k$ may be written as $2n$ for some integer $n$. How can you apply this here? Try out some examples to get a feel for the relations at hand

Comment: $2(a+b)$ is always even, $a^n$ as the same parity as $a$ for all $n>0$.

Comment: I can see how I can prove if it had a number in power like a square or a cube but I am not understanding how can we prove a variable is symmetric without supposing something. @StephenDonovan We could use 2k for n since it is even for some integer k but I don't see it getting me anywhere.

Comment: @Abrehman20 Just show that $aSb \leftrightarrow bSa.$ Once you write out what both sides of the implication are you should see that it's very trivial

Comment: @StephenDonovan so I can also write part (a) as a relation of S on Z as2|an+bn?